# Group a list of url strings based on folder structure

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a list of urls (which are stored in my database) along with a "total visits" value; I would like to somehow group all the pages by folder, then add up the total page visits for that folder. So for example, here is my source data:

```
/home                    100
/products/ice-cream      150
/products/chocolate      50
/products/pancakes       20
/about/                  80
/contact/                50
```

And here is my intended result:

```
/home                    100
/products/               220
/about/                  80
/contact/                50
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Here is my code so far, which just renders out the url next to it's visit count:

```
var Items = new List<dynamic>();
ConnectionStringSettings cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"];
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs.ToString()))
{
    string sql = "SELECT url, visits FROM url";
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Items.Add(new
            {
                Url = reader["url"],
                Visits = reader["visits"],
            });
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}

if(Items.Count > 0)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach(var item in Items)
        {
            <li>@item.Url: @item.Visits</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: How many urls are there?

Comment: By folders only 1st level or by all levels?

Comment: I'd probably want to do this same using multiple sites, so every url count will be dynamic. Top level would be preferable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using Linq GroupBy:

```
var folderVisits =  items.GroupBy(x => x.Url.Substring(0, x.Url.Remove(0, 1).IndexOf('/')))
                         .Select(x=> new { Folder = x.Key, TotalVisits = x.Sum(y => y.Visits)});
```

You have to add a `/` to `/home` for this to work though.

Comment: What's about /xxxx/yyy/zzzz?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `Dictionary<string,int>` which maps a directory to its visits.

Then you may add them:

```
private Dictionary<string,int> dictionary;

//... (Remember to initialize the dictionary!)

private void AddVisits(string directory, int visits) {

    string[] segments = Regex.Split("(\\|\/)+", directory);

    string topLevelDir = (directory.StartsWith("/") || directory.StartsWith("\\")) ?
                          segments[1] :
                          segments[0];

    topLevelDir = "/" + topLevelDir;

    int newVisits = visits;
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(topLevelDir))
       newVisits += dictionary[topLevelDir];
    dictionary[topLevelDir] = newVisits;
}
```

**NOTE**: I made this on the fly. It may have runtime errors, so feel free to comment any problems you encounter

Answer (score 0):

My recommended code:

```
var folderVisits = items.GroupBy(i => new String(i.Url.TrimStart('/').TakeWhile(c => c != '/').ToArray()), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                        .Select(grp => new {Folder = grp.Key, Visits = grp.Sum(_ => _.Visits)})
                        .ToArray();
```